# Electron tray app position on Mac OS

Tags: javascript, macos, electron

I am building an electron tray app for Mac OS. Everything seems okay, but if I run the app on one desktop and then switch to another, when I click on app icon, app returns me back to place where it was launched. How can I fix it to be open on every desktop?
Thanks in advance

```
// Sets variables (const)
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, Tray} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const assetsDirectory = path.join(__dirname, 'img')

let tray = undefined
let window = undefined

// Don't show the app in the doc
app.dock.hide()

// Creates tray & window
app.on('ready', () => {
  createTray()
  createWindow()
})

// Quit the app when the window is closed
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  app.quit()
})

// Creates tray image & toggles window on click
const createTray = () => {
  tray = new Tray(path.join(assetsDirectory, 'icon.png'))
  tray.on('click', function (event) {
         toggleWindow()
  })
}

  const getWindowPosition = () => {
  const windowBounds = window.getBounds()
  const trayBounds = tray.getBounds()

  // Center window horizontally below the tray icon
  const x = Math.round(trayBounds.x + (trayBounds.width / 2) - (windowBounds.width / 2))

  // Position window 4 pixels vertically below the tray icon
  const y = Math.round(trayBounds.y + trayBounds.height + 3)

  return {x: x, y: y}
}

// Creates window & specifies its values
const createWindow = () => {
  window = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 250,
        height: 310,
        show: false,
        frame: false,
        fullscreenable: false,
        resizable: false,
        transparent: true,
        'node-integration': false
    })
    // This is where the index.html file is loaded into the window
    window.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');

  // Hide the window when it loses focus
  window.on('blur', () => {
    if (!window.webContents.isDevToolsOpened()) {
      window.hide()
    }
  })
}

const toggleWindow = () => {
  if (window.isVisible()) {
    window.hide()
  } else {
    showWindow()
  }
}

const showWindow = () => {
  const position = getWindowPosition()
  window.setPosition(position.x, position.y, false)
  window.show()
  window.focus()
}

ipcMain.on('show-window', () => {
  showWindow()
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either call [`win.setVisibleOnAllWorkspaces(true);`](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#winsetvisibleonallworkspacesvisible) or call [`app.dock.hide();`](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#appdockhide-macos)

[`win.setVisibleOnAllWorkspaces(true);`](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#winsetvisibleonallworkspacesvisible) Does what it says and makes the window visible on all workspaces.

[`app.dock.hide();`](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#appdockhide-macos) Hides the dock icon for your application but will allow all windows in your application to be visible on all workspaces.

I think in your case you should go with [`win.setVisibleOnAllWorkspaces(true);`](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#winsetvisibleonallworkspacesvisible)

`win.setVisibleOnAllWorkspaces();` https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#winsetvisibleonallworkspacesvisible

`app.dock.hide();` https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#appdockhide-macos