# Hide window of electron app on workspace change (on macOS)

Tags: electron, window, tray

In this [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45268762/electron-tray-app-position-on-mac-os)  is described, how to get a background tray app working on multiple workspaces (on macOS).

But when using the given code example with the `win.setVisibleOnAllWorkspaces(true)` property set, I can observe the following behaviour on macOS Mojave:

If the electron app is visible in one workspace and I switch to another workspace (either by trackpad swiping or by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>), it is already visible on the reaching workspace for a short time and becomes hidden when the workspace change is completed.

Even more unwanted: When switching from one fullscreen app to another, the overlaying electron app disappears even on starting the swipe and pops up for a millisecond on the reaching workspace, after the workspace change is finished.

This behaviour can easily be reproduced by using [the tray example](https://github.com/electron/simple-samples/tree/master/electron-tray) in the electron repo and adding the `win.setVisibleOnAllWorkspaces(true)` property to it.

Is there a possibility to avoid this unnatural behaviour in a way, that the electron tray app becomes hidden as soon as a switch to another workspace is initiated?

I found the [`swipe`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-swipe-macos) event of the BrowserWindow class, but this doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a good pattern for this?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: Do we have a solution yet, two years later?  I'm noticing the same behavior.